# NextAuth GitHub provider: "no access token provided"

Tags: reactjs, express, authentication, next.js, next-auth

#### Setup

This setup uses an Express.js endpoint instead of the usual Next.js kind. The endpoint is based on [this comment](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/531#issuecomment-720261168). Also, in order to make requests from a Next.js app to an Express.js server, a `rewrites()` is added in the Next.js config ([over here](https://github.com/BorisTheTripper/nextauth-token-error/blob/99e896f0d1a7ff10afa668b031b8f8b358e3edeb/apps/client/next.config.mjs#L3)).

#### Problem

The NextAuth sign-in endpoint itself seems to work, but two issues arise when trying to sign in with GitHub

1. when the `redirect_uri` is not specified in the auth options, you'll get a `redirect_uri_mismatch` error
2. when you do specify it, things go smoothly until you get a `no access token provided` error

**P.S.:** I haven't checked with other providers, but I suspect it may happen with others, too.

#### Reproduce

The steps below will help reproduce the second error ("no access token provided"). To see the first error ("redirect_uri_mismatch"), comment out the authorization param in `packages/api/src/auth/options.ts` ([over here](https://github.com/BorisTheTripper/nextauth-token-error/blob/22bd2208b5ecc6e1e6777c907300e93956484974/packages/api/src/auth/options.ts#L21)) and follow these same steps.

1. `git clone https://github.com/BorisTheTripper/nextauth-token-error.git`
2. (Optionally) change the existing oauth credentials in `.env` with your own. If you do, make sure to configure your GitHub oauth app as follows:

   [image]
3. `pnpm install`
4. `pnpm run dev`
5. Go to `localhost:3000` while watching the terminal logs. If you see an `ECONNREFUSED` error, just go to `apps/server/src/main.ts` ([over here](https://github.com/BorisTheTripper/nextauth-token-error/blob/main/apps/server/src/main.ts)), edit the file slightly & save to trigger nodemon one more time. After this, refresh the broser page & you should see NextAuth logs in the server app.
6. **Click "sign in" button** & watch what happens in the logs as you attempt to sign in.